# Java: wrestle back control from method call

Tags: java, methods, interrupt

In implementing solutions to two problems (a finite state machine, and genetic programming), I face the same problem of effectively wanting to cancel the execution of a method.
Taking the Finite State Machine as an example, I have

```
  public class FiniteStateMachine {

    public class runState(State state) {
      state.run();
    }

  }
```

I don't have control over `State`, all I can do is call its `run` method.  Sometimes `state` might be badly behaved, for instance they may take too much time or too many bytecodes. I want to stop them, i.e. cancel the run.  How can I do this, without being able to change State, only FiniteStateMachine and with single threaded code.

Comment: Take a look at [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). But, that will required multiple threads.

Comment: There is no way to do this without using multiple threads.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That won't help.

Comment: Just one more option that I could see, that can be done is - going beyond java. While you launch your java single threaded process in a multi-tasking env like unix, you can create a pid  file at launch and let there be periodic task (watchdog) that will keep a watch on the task launched and kill the task when it thinks as the right time. Your  java task can keep writing details to flat file to keep the watch dog posted about current state of task. Since this is not a Java alone solution, I am not posting it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have control over State, all I can do is call its run method.
>   How can I do this, without being able to change State, only
>   FiniteStateMachine and with single threaded code.

Unfortunately impossible, as per the specification of the language. This will only be possible with multi-threaded approaches.

If you could modify State you could potentially do it single-threaded, but if State is black box then you're really stuck. There's just no way.